# group and merge duplicate values from groupby column as one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, multi-index

i have a dataframe of string values for all of my columns, my end result is a pdf output using reportlab, i have below issues

```
   df = pd.DataFrame({'Token' : ['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c'],
                   'value1' : ['abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno','pqr','stu','vwx','xyz'],
                   'value2' :['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','eee','fff','ggg','hhh','iii']})
  print(df)
```

```
Token value1 value2
0     a    abc    aaa
1     a    def    bbb
2     a    ghi    ccc
3     b    jkl    ddd
4     b    mno    eee
5     b    pqr    fff
6     c    stu    ggg
7     c    vwx    hhh
8     c    xyz    iii
```

I have tried, groupby, setting index, setting multindex and sort_values
I am looking for a result similar to below, appreciate any help on this.

```
    Token value1 value2
0          abc    aaa
1     a    def    bbb
2          ghi    ccc
3          jkl    ddd
4     b    mno    eee
5          pqr    fff
6          stu    ggg
7     c    vwx    hhh
8          xyz    iii
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```py
def fn(g):
    t = g["Token"].iat[0]
    g["Token"] = ""
    g["Token"].iat[len(g) // 2] = t
    return g


df = df.groupby("Token", group_keys=False).apply(fn)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Token value1 value2
0          abc    aaa
1     a    def    bbb
2          ghi    ccc
3          jkl    ddd
4     b    mno    eee
5          pqr    fff
6          stu    ggg
7     c    vwx    hhh
8          xyz    iii
```

Comment: Thanks you heaps Andrej, this worked perfectly :)